# saving to xml document

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I am "**trying**" to figure out how to create a **Windows Phone 7 application** and I would like to update/save an xml file with the following function:

```
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("myApp.xml");

        xmlDoc.Element("ocd").Add(new XElement("vDetails", new XElement("itemName", this.tb_Name.Text),
            new XElement("Date", System.DateTime.Now.ToString()), new XElement("itemValue", "")));

        xmlDoc.Save("data.xml");
```

However the xmlDoc.Save line is giving an error:  The best overloaded method match for "System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save(System.Xml.XmlWriter) has some invalid arguments.

What do I need to do to correct this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to save to isolated storage (or a few other places). Get the isolated storage for your application, open a stream to a file, and save to the stream:

```
using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (Stream stream = storage.CreateFile("data.xml"))
    {
        doc.Save(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  This example set me down the correct path...  I was wondering though...  When I save the file it appears to save when I show the updated file.  However, with using Iso storage if the "app" is closed does the newly updated .xml file get saved and restored?  I can't seem to figure out how to test that?  Any suggestions?  Maybe I need to ask this as a question.

Comment: @Jeff: Isolated storage is persistent. You can think of it as your application's own private disk. If the app is uninstalled and then reinstalled, I suspect it'll be wiped though.

Comment: @JonSkeet hi, so that way you explain is for saving the xml file, but if i want to read that same file using that logic ?

`var xml = XDocument.Load("arquivo.xml").ToString();
            var content = new StringContent(
                xml,
                Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"),
                "application/xml");`

Comment: @NathielPaulino: Well just the call to `XDocument.Load` reads the file. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, to be honest - nor is it likely that ISO-8859-1 is the right encoding to use. It sounds like you should probably ask a new question with more details.

Comment: @JonSkeet  i already did but, nobody answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34554496/how-to-access-file-inside-of-isolatedstoragefilestream-windows-phone-8-1)

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Phone developer blog goes talks application execution model in great depth.

I think it is important to distinguish between application 'closing' and an application being tombstoned.

> **Application Closing** is simply the
>   outcome of the user pressing the
>   hardware Back button enough times to
>   navigate backwards through the pages
>   of your application, past the
>   application’s first page.
>
> **Application Deactivated** occurs when a
>   different application takes control of
>   the foreground - for example, an
>   incoming phone call, launching a
>   chooser, or the user pressing the
>   Windows button. In both cases, your
>   application will be deactivated (not
>   closed). Before we step into the
>   subtleties of the Deactivated event,
>   let’s make sure we all understand that
>   upon Deactivation, your application
>   gets terminated (at the end). It's
>   that simple; your code can’t run in
>   the background, therefore your
>   application gets terminated. However,
>   unlike an application that is closed,
>   a deactivated application gets
>   tombstoned. Don’t get confused, a
>   tombstoned application’s process still
>   gets terminated. But unlike a closed
>   application, where the WP operating
>   system removes any trace of the
>   application, when an application is
>   deactivated, the WP operating system
>   stores a record (a tombstone) of the
>   application's state. Basically, the WP
>   operating system keeps a tombstone of
>   the application that becomes part of
>   the phone’s application back-stack,
>   which is a journal that enables the
>   use of the hardware Back button to
>   enhance navigation functionality.

[Application Execution Model](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/15/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-choosers-and-few-more-things-that-are-on-the-way-part-1.aspx)

As for testing, an idea may be to refactor the code and add logging for various event points like closing or being tombstoned etc.