# How can i save my XML File on windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, linq-to-xml

I want to save a database on a windows phone using Linq. On my Desktop PC I could easly save the XML file with a string as:

```
XDoc.Save(@"Assets\Database.xml");
```

and on Windows Phone i could even read like:

```
XDoc.Load(@"Assets\Database.xml");
```

But now i want save and i dont have the Option to set the save location via string, because it can not convert from String to Stream. But I have no Idea how i can save my XML File now. :/
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [saving to xml document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217594/saving-to-xml-document)

Comment: Does anybody know something? This is for Win7 i dont have access to
IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()).